# .htaccess and PHP for multiple parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I need a little help(I am not a pro),

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ url.php?p1=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ url.php?p1=$1&p2=$2 [L]
```

and I would like to display the content on the basis of number of parameters (on the basis of type(in future))
What I wish to know is

```
$p1 = $_GET['p1'];
$p2 = $_GET['p2'];
if p2 = ""
{
echo "something";
}
else
{
echo "something";
}
```

Will the above code work without any issue?

What all errors can occur?

Is there a better way to handle this?

How wordpress handles this?

Note: I wish to display the contents on the basis of more than 3 params and type of params as well.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself and see if it works "without any issue"?

Comment: What a rude comment ..

Comment: No, it won't work, no correct syntax

Comment: Is this actually for use with wordpress or is this something you are doing completely outside of it?

Comment: @prodigitalson No this is not to use with WordPress. I am doing something completely outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking this isn't the greatest way to go about it. It's better to use a router which basically uses a single htaccess rule to catch all requests where a file/folder doesn't exist and then send them to a single php file. That file then initializes the router which figures out what the parameters are based on patterns matched against the request URI.

For example using the [`symfony/routing` component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html) in index.php:

```
// this is our index.php
// assuming we installed with composer
// and that the vendor dir is one level up from the document root
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

// Create a Route Collection
$routes = new RouteCollection();

// lets use an array to define our routes
$routeDefinitions = array(
    'foo_archive' => array(
        // note the {} wraped parts are params
       'path' => '/foo/{p1}/{p2}',
       'defaults' => array('controller' => 'foo/archive.php'),
       'requirements' => array(
           // not a very specific match but lets pretend this matches a 
           // category or something
           'p1'=> '[a-z0-9-_]+', 
           // matches a date
           'p2'=> '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}', 
       )
       // there are other things we can add like options, a requrired host, 
       // or a specific HTTP mehtod (PUT, GET, POST, etc.)
    ),
    'foo_index' => array(
       'path' => '/foo',
       'defaults' => array('controller' => 'foo/index.php')
    );
);

// let's add our routes
$routeReflector = new \ReflectionClass('Symfony\Component\Routing\Route'); 

foreach ($routeDefinitions as $name => $def) {
    $routes->add($name, $routeReflector->newInstanceArgs($def));
}



$context = new RequestContext($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $context);

$parameters = $matcher->match($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);

    /* so assuming PATH_INFO matched one of our patterns and its     
       requirements parameters will be an array - 
       lets pretend PATH_INFO had:  /foo/bar/2014-04-20
   
        so we would have an array like:

        array(
            'controller' => 'archive.php', 
            '_route' => 'foo_archive', 
            'p1' => 'bar', 
            'p2' => '2014-04-20'
        )
    */

    $controllersDir = realpath(__DIR__ . '/controllers');
    $controller = $controllersDir . '/' . $parameters['controller'];
    if (file_exists($controller) {
       // include our controller and let it do its work
       // note that normally you would be instantiating a controller object
       // here and invoking some method on it, but for ease of example lets
       // just assume it a normal php file with all the logic for the page
       include($controller);
    } else {
       // generate a 500 or 404 error depending on how you want to handle
       // it
    }
```

And then your .htaccess would be something like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
```

Alternatively, if you are open to it you could use a Microframework like [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html) which would wire all this up for you and give an out of the box way to do things.

Silex Example (index.php):

```
// assuming we installed with Composer
// and that the vendor dir is one level up from the document root
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; 

$app = new Silex\Application(); 

// you can define routes as closures like this but normally
// I prefer to use classes... You can look at the docs for
// how to do that: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#controllers-in-classes
$app->get('/foo/{p1}/{p2}', function($p1, $p2) use($app) { 
    // do whatever logic you need to do to render the page 
});

$app->get('/foo}', function() use($app) { 
    // do whatever logic you need to do to render the page 
}); 

$app->run();
```